# DB2: Extract definition of a global temp table created using "as select"

Tags: db2

In a perl dbi script, I need to create a db2 temp table on database A using "as select" to define columns. 
Then, I need to redefine the temp table on another database B.
Does any of you have any hints on how to generate the ddl of the global temp table on database A?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can always build DDL by accessing the catalog tables

```
SELECT 
    NAME || ' ' || COLTYPE || '(' || CHAR(LENGTH) || ') ,'
 FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS   
WHERE TBNAME = ?
AND TBCREATOR = USER
```

Set the ? parameter to the name of the GTT's name.